# Java - Adding Functionality by Adding a New Class Without Modifying Anything Else

Tags: java, reflection

How is it possible to have classes `A`, `B`, `C`, with functionality F, and then add class `D` to `bin/` and get different functionality than F without modifying `A`, `B` or `C` in any way?

I've seen this done in [ModLoader](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/75440-v147-risugamis-mods-updated/) for Minecraft. With ModLoader, you copy the classes over from ModLoader to Minecraft. You can then simply drop a new class that starts with "mod_" into the Minecraft jar and it adds new things to the game. At no point is there any classes that reference your "mod_Foobar" class directly.

A small working example, and links to any further reading is preferable.

Comment: I tagged `reflection` because I have a feeling it's involved (although I don't really know anything about it). If you know it is unrelated, please say so, or remove it.

Comment: I don't know exactly HOW, but i think you shuold be able to somehow find all classes that are on your classpath, and then load them via reflection. Or you could just find the .class files and load them through some mechanism (javassist should work, but there is probably also something else). Eclipse does such things through configuration files (loading it's plugins, that is). And so on... It all burns down to looking for the files you may want to use on the classpath.

Comment: Could this be the Strategy Design Pattern in action ? : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_design_pattern

Comment: After looking into reflection, I am finally starting to understand what it does. My question's answer is basically: "reflection", which I tagged. I essentially answered my question in the tags. The question is overly broad. Feel free to vote to close as it's "not a real question."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Reflection {

    public void sayHello(String theClass){
        //Since Mod classes are in package 'mod', we precede their name accordingly.
        Class aClass = Class.forName("mod." + theClass);
        aClass.getMethod("sayHi").invoke(aClass.newInstance());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Get a list of the compiled classes in the 'mod' folder
        String path = "./bin/mod";
        String fileName;
        File folder = new File(path);
        List<File> fileList = Arrays.asList(folder.listFiles());
        //Iterate through the list of classes to invoke their methods
        Iterator<File> it = fileList.iterator();        
        while(it.hasNext()){
            fileName = it.next().getName();     
            //When invoking the sayHello method, we remove the file extension
            new Reflection().sayHello(fileName.replace(".class", ""));
        }

    }
}
```

Class ModA:

```
public class ModA {
    public void sayHi(){
        System.out.println("Hi! I'm ModA.");        
    }   
}
```

Class ModB:

```
public class ModB {
    public void sayHi(){
        System.out.println("Hi! I'm ModB.");        
    }   
}
```

Please note:

- I've removed some necessary exception handling in order to clarify the example.
- The Mod classes are located in a package called 'mod'. After compilation, they are present in bin/mod. There might be a cleaner way of scanning for them.
- The Mod classes are compiled, packed into a jar and included in the build path.

Answer (score 0):

The classpath is used to load classes and it's ordered, so if you place your class BEFORE an original class, yours will be loaded and not the original.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's all about applying basic OO principles.

Simple inheritance allows you to achieve [polymorphisme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29). In a well designed system this is a good starting point to get new behavior into a system.

The [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) is another software design pattern in your toolbox, where an algorithm's behaviour can be selected at runtime.

The [factory pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html) (combined with reflection and the patterns mentioned above) can create a system where you can "drop" classes into an existing system in order to add new functionality without changing its core.

You can also do [classpath scanning](http://bill.burkecentral.com/2008/01/14/scanning-java-annotations-at-runtime/) to find interesting (annotated) classes at startup to modify runtime behavior.

I'm sure MindCraft is a well designed system applying a lot more patterns than the ones described here.

Ultimately, it all boils down to good design and applying the correct patterns at the right place.